# Адаптация таблицы для мобильных устройств

Tags: html, css

Есть следующая таблица:

```
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th><b>Экономный тариф</b><span>30 руб.</span></th>
            <th><b>Стандартный тариф</b><span>60 руб.</span></th>
            <th><b>Безлимитный тариф</b><span>120 руб.</span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td> Фича раз</td>
            <td> - </td>
            <td> - </td>
            <td> + </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Фича два</td>
            <td> - </td>
            <td> + </td>
            <td> + </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Фича три </td>
            <td> + </td>
            <td> + </td>
            <td> + </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

На планшетах и мобильных устройствах (<768px) должен отображаться всего лишь один столбец с тарифом (примерно так) с тремя кнопками-переключателями:

```
          Экономный тариф
          30руб.
Фича раз  -
Фича два  -
Фича три  +
```

При нажатии на вторую кнопку должен показываться второй столбец, при нажатии на третью -- третий. При нажатии на первую кнопку должен вновь показываться первый столбец.

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: А блоками не вариант сделать? Попроще будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.first-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    // При клике на первую кнопку - показываем первую колонку.
    // Потом скрываем вторую и третью
    // Подобный механизм при клике на вторую и третью кнопку
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.first').show();
    $('.second').hide();
    $('.third').hide();
  })
  $('.second-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.second').show();
    $('.first').hide();
    $('.third').hide();
  })
  $('.third-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.third').show();
    $('.second').hide();
    $('.first').hide();
  })
})
```

```css
// Используем медиа запрос для экранов меньше 768 px, прячем блок с кнопками на экранах большего размера
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .buttons {
    display: block;
  }
  .second {
    display: none;
  }
  .third {
    display: none;
  }
}

.buttons {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="first-btn">Экономный тариф</button>
  <button class="second-btn">Стандартный тариф</button>
  <button class="third-btn">Безлимитный тариф</button>
</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="first"><b>Экономный тариф</b><span>30 руб.</span></th>
      <th class="second"><b>Стандартный тариф</b><span>60 руб.</span></th>
      <th class="third"><b>Безлимитный тариф</b><span>120 руб.</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="feature-first">
      <td> Фича раз</td>
      <td class="first"> - </td>
      <td class="second"> - </td>
      <td class="third"> + </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="feature-second">
      <td>Фича два</td>
      <td class="first"> - </td>
      <td class="second"> + </td>
      <td class="third"> + </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="feature-third">
      <td>Фича три </td>
      <td class="first"> + </td>
      <td class="second"> + </td>
      <td class="third"> + </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Проверяйте код на экранах с расширением меньше чем `768px`.